# Give an example of a graph $G$ with genus $2$ and $\chi(G)=\chi(S_2)$.

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example of a graph $G$ with genus $2$ and $\chi(G)=\chi(S_2)$.

I know the answer is $G=K_8$. But I would like to understand how to do problem like this.

From the question, I can tell that $G$ is embedded in $S_2$. So $\chi(G) \leq \chi(S_2)$.

By Headwood Map-coloring theorem, I know that for $k$ is positive

$$\chi(S_k) =\lfloor {\frac{7+\sqrt{1+48k}}{2} } \rfloor$$
so

$$\chi(S_2) =\lfloor {\frac{7+\sqrt{1+48(2)}}{2} } \rfloor=8$$

Since $\chi(S_2) = max \{\chi(G)\}$ and  $\chi(G)=\chi(S_2)$,  so $\chi(G)=8$

I know that $\chi(K_8)=8$, but there are many other graphs that are $8$-chromatic. Why it has to be $K_8$?

I wonder if anyone would please tell me if there is any info from the question that I've missed.

Comment: What is the $S_2$ graph?

Comment: $S_2$ is not a graph, it's a surface, where $G$ embedded in

Comment: Oh, okay. What surface is it?

Comment: $S_0$ is a sphere, $S_1$ is a torus, $S_2$ look like 2 donuts glued together :D

Comment: My conjecture? I did not make a conjecture?

Comment: @Nishant That was in response to me. I'm not really informed about the relation between colorings and the Euler characteristic, so I deleted a question about my confusion. Perhaps it would be easiest to produce a simplicial model of $S_n$ inductively and explicitly compute the Euler characteristic from the number of simplices in each dimension? I'm trying this myself.

Comment: Okay, that worked, but of course you weren't trying to calculate the Euler characteristic of the $k$-hole torus, but the minimum number of colors necessary to color all graphs on the $k$-hole torus. I should have read more carefully.